# Unable to Hit Rest Controller Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I have below pom.xml in the SpringBoot application. While running the application, I am not facing any errors. But when I am hitting the URL through postman or browser, then my java code present inside controller is not getting executed.

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>MENU-RIGHT</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.model.MenuRightModel;
import com.example.service.MenuRightService;

@RestController
public class MenuRightController {

    Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    @Autowired
    private MenuRightService menuRightService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value  = "/getRightByUser/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public MenuRightModel findRightByUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        logger.info("Request Received for User Id : "+id);
        return menuRightService.findRightByUser(id);
        
    }
    @RequestMapping(value  = "/getRightAll", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public MenuRightModel findAllRight() {
        return new MenuRightModel();
        
    }
}
```

**Project Execution Screenshot:**

[image]

**Postman Execution Screenshot:**
[image]
[image]

**Spring Boot Application Class:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("src/main/java")
public class MenuRightApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SpringApplication.run(MenuRightApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot Repository Class:**

```
package com.dbs.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.model.MenuRightModel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface MenuRightRepository extends JpaRepository<MenuRightModel, Integer>{
    MenuRightModel findByUserId(int id);
}
```

**After Adding BasePackage as com.example facing below Exception:**

2022-03-21 09:51:35.169  WARN 20560 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'menuRightController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'menuRightService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'menuRightServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'menuRightRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repository.MenuRightRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-03-21 09:51:35.172  INFO 20560 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-03-21 09:51:35.189  INFO 20560 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-21 09:51:35.312 ERROR 20560 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field menuRightRepository in com.example.service.impl.MenuRightServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.MenuRightRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.MenuRightRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Does `localhost:8080/api/getRightAll` hit your endpoint?

Comment: No. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is your main class configuration issue. By default, framework will scan beans in same package as of main class and sub-packages. e.g. below will not work

com/example/controller/FooController.java

com/example/main/MainClass.java

as applciation will scan for beans in com.example.main package and its subpackages only.

If that is case, you will need to update 'scanBasePackages' attribute of @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: Added main class. Kindly look into it.

Comment: "src/main/java" is not a package but just maven source folder structure. You may not need `@ComponentScan` here as `@SpringBootApplication` will scan it. 

Also, scanning a default package is not encouraged as it will include all libraries as well.

So can you please try 
1. Keeping main class in some package like "com.exmaple"
and keep controller classes in "com.example.controller", keep repositories in "com.exmaple.repository" ?
2. Remove `@ComponentScan`

This should help you.

Comment: @RanganRay - if any of the answers has helped you to resolve issue, you can accept that answer. It will help others as well who will visit this page in future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a package name in the component scan, in your case, it is @ComponentScan("com.example.controller"), Standard way to create other packages is
under the main root package

Comment: Added the base package. Facing the above-attached exception while starting the application.

Comment: you need to add all the packages in component scan, Eg: @ComponentScan({"com.example.controller"."com.example,service","com.example.dao}) etc. instead of adding this, you can follow the standard package structure.     com.example -> com.example.controller -> com.example. service -> com.example.dao etc